# Register with object with AutoFac

Tags: autofac, rebus

I'm using Rebus.  In the AutofacContainerAdapter (https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/master/src/Rebus.Autofac/AutofacContainerAdapter.cs) they are calling the following line of code:

```
builder.Register(a => MessageContext.GetCurrent()).ExternallyOwned();
```

How can setup my MessageHandler constructor so that Autofac can find back this type?  If I understand it correctly, when I use `IMessageContext` in my constructor, it won't be passed because there is no `.As<IMessageContext>()` in the code above.

Comment: but `GetCurrent()` returns an `IMessageContext` - doesn't that make Autofac automatically register it as that?

Comment: It's IMessageContext indeed.  there was an other parameter in my constructor going nuts.  I need the IMessageContext to unit test, so can't use MessageContext.GetCurrent().  Or can I?

Comment: for unit testing I recommend injecting `IMessageContext`, just like you're about to - but there is a thing called `FakeMessageContext` that can be used to set up something fake that will be returned by `MessageContext.GetCurrent()`, so it IS possible - it's just easier (and better code design IMO) to inject it :)

Comment: Doing that currently.  Thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at: https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/master/src/Rebus/MessageContext.cs shows:

```
public static IMessageContext GetCurrent()
{
}
```

So that registers as `IMessageContext`. If you don't explicitly state otherwise, a lambda registration implicitly registers as the return type of the lambda.